# SQL query too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the requery below to clean up a table but I have the status "Sending data" for hours. It is a MySQL DB.

```
DELETE TABLE_INIT FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit TABLE_INIT
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                    SELECT MIN(id_url) as id, id_ann
                    FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit
                    GROUP BY id_ann
                ) AS TABLE_1
                ON TABLE_INIT.id_url = TABLE_1.id
WHERE TABLE_1.id IS NULL
```

The table has the following structure

```
id_url | id_ann | url | eaa
```

My primary key is id_url and table indexed on id_ann.

I have a huge qty of identical data that I want to remove and set id_ann as primary key to fix my issue. There are 13M lines in the table.

Do I need to do it in several time ? What is the best way to clean up the table ?

Thanks

Comment: Add this index `ALTER TABLE DEM_annonces_urlproduit  ADD KEY(id_ann,id_url)` This will allow the subquery to use loose index scan which is every efficient.It will take some time for 13 mil rows,so be patient.

Comment: I always like to see the progress of such "huge" operations, so I'd probably wrap it up in a function and divide into parts with some logging mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize your statement:

```
DELETE FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit
WHERE id NOT IN (
      SELECT MIN(id_url)
      FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit
      GROUP BY id_ann
)
```

When it does not get much better, loop over select

```
  SELECT MIN(id_url) id, id_ann
  FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit
  GROUP BY id_ann
```

and delete only within group

```
DELETE FROM DEM_annonces_urlproduit
WHERE id <> current.id
AND id_ann = current.id_ann
```